# Google Chrome (v.51) not applying print media css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, media-queries

I know there's a lot of questions about this, but I tried everything and nothing seems to work. I followed these links:

[Splitting HTML page so Printer splits it into separate pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686883/splitting-html-page-so-printer-splits-it-into-separate-pages)

[Chrome: Print preview differs from simulate CSS media print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529683/chrome-print-preview-differs-from-simulate-css-media-print?rq=1)

[Print media queries being ignored in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650543/print-media-queries-being-ignored-in-chrome)

[Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)

and much more.

I tried pretty much every single suggestion in all of them.

Here's what I've got so far :

**html**

```
<link href="path/styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
<div class="page-break">
      //some stuff
</div>
```

**css**

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always;}
}
```

In IE and FF, I can't see preview of the page I'll print, but when I do print, it works just fine. In chrome, I can see preview, but it's never right... next I'm trying to save it as pdf, but it still doesn't apply print css.

*Saving as pdf as nothing to do with trying to make it works... it's just to save paper

Now, before you post an answer, please be aware of the following :

I tried this:

- !important; hack
- Deleting css page and put css directly in html page
- Delete media all
- Delete media all and changing display block to none
- Tried page-break-inside: avoid;
- *{transition:none !important;}
- .page-break { ... transition: none !important;}
- put it in main style sheet
- float: none !important;
- position: relative; position: static;
- display: block; display: inline;
- box-sizing: content-box;
- -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;

I didn't try with other version of Chrome. I tried on v.50, after multiple attempt fail, I updated to v.51. Some said it works on v.38 or something like that... I won't downgrade to that version.

Edit: I forgot to mention that my html code is in a jsp page. So the `<div class="page-break">` is in a `for-loop`. Every loop has to be on individual page.

Edit 2: I created a jsfiddle. I pasted the source code I have and it works perfectly. So I removed the css stylesheet that are links in my page. But even by doing that, it won't work. So if it's override somewhere, it's not there.

The page is a JSP page, does it have anything to do about it? If not I'm clueless, because in the same project, on the page I want to print, I added a button that redirect to a page.html and I created 3 divs with the same class name and it works just fine.

Comment: This might not be the issue, but maybe the classname is causing some conflict? Its a stab in the dark, but easy enough to try.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar Nice try, sadly it didn't change a thing!

Comment: Try adding 'float: none' as well to the css class .page-break; try stuff in this basically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884380/css-page-break-not-working-in-all-browsers

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar I was crossing my fingers... but no, none of those answers worked. I added the style in the same order, all with !important.. it won't work!

Comment: -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid; in there might help, but thats the last thing I can think of, other than an issue if one of the parent elements do not have position relative. Note: all parent elements should be block level as well.

Comment: Yea I already tried -webkit-region-break-inside. I'm afraid the display is set to block to the parent as well

Comment: I sadly have to bow out my friend, hope someone else knows enough to help.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's an issue with me, I just created a jsfiddle and it works just fine...

Comment: Possibly a hidden css somewhere overriding and causing the issue.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar Thanks for your follow up. It just made me think of other solution, without you I'd probably be still searching how to make it work!

Comment: No probs, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

So! I'm here to answer my own question, in case someone just can't make it work just like me.

I tried to give a new approach to my problem, since I can't print single div per page and I don't know why, I must find another way. But it's not that I didn't know how it works... I created a JSFiddle and it worked. In my own project, I created a html page and it worked. But since I was in JSP, maybe it was messing with my code somewhere.. I have no idea.

So here's what I've done.

```
function getStuffToPrint(data){
        var html = "", index, len;
        for (index = 0, len = data.length; index < len; ++index) {
            html += "<div class=\"custom-page-break\">" + data[index].innerHTML + "</div>";
        }
        var mywindow = window.open();
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
            mywindow.document.write('<link href="my/path/to/styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(html);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus();

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
    }
```

In my case, `data` was an `objectHTMLCollection` : `document.getElementsByClassName("custom-page-break")`

It's a bit ratchet, I had to write the `div` with the class name again...

Here's my css, it may work without `display: block` and `page-break-inside`, I didn't even try.

```
@media print {
    .custom-page-break  { 
        display: block !important;
        page-break-before: always !important;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
}
```

Hope it'll save hours for some people.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the print.css in your main style css document ? I had a similar case and it solved my problem.

You dont have to make a pdf file every time to see if the @media print worked, you can see the page emulated like print in your Google developpement tool on Chrome:

[image: Media print for google chrome]

To see that option, do : F12 -> show console -> rendering ( it's a tab of the console ) -> check "Emulate media Print".

Comment: Thansk for quick answer. Yes I forgot to mention it, at first it was in my main style.css, it didn't work so I moved it in another css file. I also tried the checkbox, but I don't understand where... Is it when I see the page, or when I click on print and see the preview? Because when I check it there's nothing refreshing or anything, it stays the same..

Comment: Actually I found what it was suppose to do. But I still can't make it work